# Large text appears blurry

Tags: c++, text, sfml, blurry

I'm using SFML 1.6 to make a small game, and I need to display some text, so I use the `sf::String` class. The problem is, when I increase the size to 96pt, the edges appear a little blurry. When I increase the size of text in Microsoft Word though, it appears very clean and has crisp edges. Is there a way to do that with SFML?

Comment: It sounds like SFML is trying to anti alias the text, i.e. make the hard, pixelated edges a bit softer. I'm not sure what MS Word does for font loading, but I'm sure they have some pretty advanced algorithms for making it crisp like you noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the SFML sources, it appears that it is using the embedded Arial font. Yes, it can also load the .ttf font file, but I guess you didn't load it yet.

So the problem is tht SFML tries to scale the fixed-size bitmap when you are rendering the text.

To get rid of the aliasing try following this sample  http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.4/graphics-fonts.php   and load the .ttf manually.