# SFML 1.6 - Blured text

Tags: c++, text, sfml

I've got a weird issue with SFML, when I want to draw a sf::String, a  kind of shadow appears inside the text.

See : http://puu.sh/2aaGs

The code :

```
text.SetSize(90);
text.SetFont(font);
text.SetText("Oktopus");
text.SetPosition(300, 300);
text.SetColor(sf::Color(255,215,0));
```

...

```
render.Draw(text);
```

edit : 
Thanks to Armin, I had to fix the size of the when I loaded it.

```
font.LoadFromFile("fonts/Minecraftia.ttf", 90)
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707083/large-text-appears-blurry-smfl-c.

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen that topic but didn't understand what I had to do. I fixed by setting a size when I load the font.

font.LoadFromFile("fonts/Minecraftia.ttf", 90)

Comment: If you found a solution, you should answer your own question below.

Comment: I can't reply to my own question for 8 hours after asking. I'm going to edit the main post.

Comment: Don't do that, either leave it alone or answer it later properly.